# Any suggestions for making this rounded box design to CSS?

Tags: html, css, psd

I have the CSS for the basic design of this rounded box. I have pasted that below. I'm trying to add a blue border with the following design effect (please see image below). Firstly is this possible? If so, any suggestions would be great..

I tried adding just a top border, but it doesn't quite give it the effect i'm looking for.

[image: Blue top border design is what I'm looking for.]

```
.contentbox {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(54, 81, 143);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.2;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -8px 0px 0px rgba(54, 81, 143, 0.03);
  position: absolute;
  left: 190px;
  top: 324px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 524px;
  z-index: 118;
}
```

Comment: Just `border-radius: 5px; border-top: 2px solid blue;` works fine for me. Is this on a website? Just inspect the element and look at its CSS then.

Comment: You can always use you browser devtools to see how the styles are applied.

Comment: No it's on a PSD file.

Answer (score 0):

[This Codepen](https://codepen.io/chroline/pen/zEdrXG) uses different border widths to create a similar effect to what is pictured in the example.
Good luck, and I hope this helps.

```css
html, body {
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-color: rgb(54, 81, 143);
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -8px 0px 0px rgba(54, 81, 143, 0.03);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```